# How to select FlatList item in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have this code :

```
renderRooms = ({item:room}) => {
  return(
    <View style={styles.cards}>
      <View style={styles.cardRight}>
        <View style={{ marginLeft:2, alignItems: 'center', flex:1 }}>
          <Text style={{fontSize:12, marginTop:10, marginBottom: 5, color:'#B0B0B0'}}>
             Harga/malam
          </Text>      
          <Text style={{fontSize:12, textDecorationLine:'line-through'}}>              
            {`${'Rp.'}${room.pricing.normal}`}
          </Text>
          <Text style={{fontSize:14, fontWeight:'800', color:'#26de81', }}>
            {`${'Rp.'}${room.pricing.discount}`}
          </Text>
          <CheckBox
            // center
            iconRight
            title={this.state.showContinueToPayment == true ? 'Batal' : 'Pilih'}                                                            
            checked={this.state.showContinueToPayment}
            containerStyle={{padding:5, borderColor:'white', backgroundColor:'white'}}
            onPress={() => this.setState({showContinueToPayment: !this.state.showContinueToPayment})}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}
```

on this part :

```
<CheckBox
  iconRight
  title={this.state.showContinueToPayment == true ? 'Batal' : 'Pilih'}                                                                                            
  checked={this.state.showContinueToPayment}
  containerStyle={{padding:5, borderColor:'white', backgroundColor:'white'}}
  onPress={() => this.setState({showContinueToPayment: !this.state.showContinueToPayment})}
/>
```

I want to be able to set the `state` of my `checkbox`, but I can't make it done.

I'm using a `FlatList`, when I render my app, this `renderRooms` give me 2 list. I think the problem is these 2 list should have their own state. But I don't know how to do it.

Looking for some helps. Thanks beforehands.

Comment: I think right before the return, but still in the render you will have the scope you want. You can just define your function there, like "handleOnCheckboxPress" and provide it the code that you currently have on OnPress. Then on OnPress you can just call that function.

Comment: Please add the code for your entire component class